# Asciidoc long chapter titles in the header area overlaps the company logo

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

My problem is the representation of long `{chapter-title}` in the header area. The long chapter titles overlaps the company logo. It would be great if I could define a short version for the header area.

[image: 1]

I'm using the `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` version 2.2.1 and `asciidoctorj-pdf-plugin` version 1.6.0 for pdf creation. The `theme.yml` has following definitions:

```yaml
recto:
    left:
        content: '{document-title}'
    right:
        content: image:logo.png[width=200]
verso:
    left:
        content: '{chapter-title}'
    right:
        content: $header-recto-right-content
```

and `example.adoc` looks as folows:

```markdown
= Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
:doctype: book
:encoding: utf-8
:lang: en
:toc: macro
:toclevels: 2
:numbered:

toc::[]

== Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<side>-columns` property to assign a specific width for your header elements. Check [Running Content (Header & Footer)](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/docs/theming-guide.adoc#running-content-header--footer) for more info.

```
header:
  recto:
    columns: <25% =50% >25%
    left:
      content: '{document-title}'
    right:
      content: image:logo.png[width=200]
```